# Problem with java.lang.NullPointerException on Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the geoareas table and the places table, in places table i only have the geoarea_id and in geoareas table i have the id and the name

My goal here is create a function that take the geoarea_id array and transform in a names array

Declaring the tables:

```
val geoareas =
(
    spark.table("location.geoareas")
)


val places = 
(
    spark.table("location.places")
    .select('id, 'name, 'geoareas, 'lat, 'lng)
)
```

Function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{concat,lit}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import scala.collection.mutable

def _searchGeocode(origin:Seq[String]): Seq[String] = {

    var retlist = Seq("@")
    for (i <- origin){
        val procvalue = geoareas.where('id ===i).select(concat('adminlevel, lit(":"), 'name)).collect()(0).toString.replace("[","").replace("]","")
        retlist ++= Seq(procvalue)
    }

    retlist.filter(!_.contains("@"))
}
```

When i test with a unique sequence, it works:

```
val test = Seq("59138c8a03205749cd00ceb3", "59138ad003205749cdfac6c4", "59138adf03205749cdfb0067", "59138ace03205749cdfabeeb")

_searchGeocode(test).filter(!_.contains("@"))
```

it returns

```
  Seq[String] = List(6:McHenry County, 8:Woodstock, 2:United States of America, 4:Illinois)
```

Obs: the number is the admin_level of the geoarea_id, with it i know if is a country, state...

The error appears when i try to transform a entire column:

```
spark.udf.register("searchGeocode", _searchGeocode _)
val searchGeocode = udf(_searchGeocode _)

places.limit(10).select('geoareas).where('geoareas.isNotNull).withColumn("test", searchGeocode('geoareas)).show()
```

it throws me:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 64.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 64.0 (TID 9047, 10.2.91.129, executor 6): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (array<string>) => array<string>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.project_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at $anonfun$_searchGeocode$1.apply(<console>:197)
    at $anonfun$_searchGeocode$1.apply(<console>:196)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
    at _searchGeocode(<console>:196)
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:192)
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:192)
    ... 22 more

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3389)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2550)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:751)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:710)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:719)
  ... 77 elided
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (array<string>) => array<string>)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.project_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
  ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at $anonfun$_searchGeocode$1.apply(<console>:197)
  at $anonfun$_searchGeocode$1.apply(<console>:196)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
  at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
  at _searchGeocode(<console>:196)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:192)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:192)
  ... 22 more
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: The problem can be there that you expects that the select will return at least one result.

Comment: @m4gic thanks for reply, i tested put a Option() in procvalue but the error continue

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but I think you want to do something like this instead:

```scala
val searchGeocode = udf(_searchGeocode)

places.limit(10).select('geoareas).where('geoareas.isNotNull).withColumn("test", searchGeocode('geoareas)).show()
```

I don't think you need `_` placeholder when using `udf` function.